# memory allocation - call by reference String-Array-Paramater

Tags: c, arrays, function, memory, pass-by-reference

The question is how to correctly allocate/free the memory in this example:

```
void test(char*** array, int* count) {

  *array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAX_ARRAY);
  while (...) {
    (*array)[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(fooString));
  }
}
```

call of the function:

```
char** array;
int count;
test(&array, &count);
// now free the memory - i think i have to?
for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  free(array[i]); // <-- crash here
}
free(array);
```

It looks like that array[0] has a different address inside the test-function than outside. How can this be? Looks like i misunderstood sth, because the address of array is the same outside and inside the function.

**Edit: The Problem is that i am not able to free the allocated memory (see "crash here" in code). Why?  And how will it work?**

Comment: not applicable to your problem, but don't cast the return value of malloc()

Comment: array[0] in test is not the same as array[0] outside of test. In test, array holds the address of the variable called array in the function calling test. Also [do not cast the return value of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: i recognized that these are two different array[0] (still don't understand why), but how am i able to free the allocated memory?

Comment: Another note: `strlen` does not include the '\0' character.

Comment: What is this `while (...)`?

Comment: your test function doesnt set count, so your free loop will run off the end

Comment: @marty You're allocating an array of MAX_ARRAY char*, but when you free the emelemts you iterate over `count` elements. if count > MAX_ARRAY, you get in trouble. If you have more code than what's shown here, e.g. a strcpy((*array)[i], fooString), you are off by one, and thrashing the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
void test(char*** array, int* count) {

  *array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAX_ARRAY);
  while (...) {
    (*array)[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(fooString));
  }
}
```

do

```
void test(char*** array, int count) {

  *array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count); // number of pointers
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) 
  {
    (*array)[i] = malloc(strlen(fooString)); 
  }
}
```

although i am not sure about what `fooString` is since you don't show the decl/def. Normally you would allocate one byte extra for the \0

```
(*array)[i] = malloc(strlen(fooString) + 1)
```

this seems to work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

char fooString[256];

void test(char*** array, int count) 
{
  int i = 0;
  *array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);
  for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) 
  {
    (*array)[i] = malloc(strlen(fooString)+1);
  }
}

int main()
{
  char** array = NULL;
  int count = 100;
  int i = 0;
  test(&array, count);


  for(i = 0; i < count;++i) 
  {
    free(array[i]); 
  }
  free(array);    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer - still the same issue... cannot free the memory outside the function

Comment: thank you so far, your example code works here too... but i am too stupid to see the difference to mine.

Comment: @claptrap You don't need to initialize i to 0, the `for` does it for you.

Comment: @Eregrith I know, it is a reflex ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I can't blame you ^^

Comment: This `*array = malloc(sizeof(char**) ...` should be `*array = malloc(sizeof(char*) ...`. your previous version was ok.

Comment: @marty: Your code defines `count` as `int *`. *claptrap*'s as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

**For your particular problem:**

You allocate `(*array)[i]` which is a `char*` to `strlen(fooString)` which is usually equivalent to `sizeof(char) * strlen(fooString)` : this is error prone. You should use `sizeof(*((*array)[i]))` in this case to be sure not to miss the correct type.

*To free it*, loop from `i = 0` to `i < MAX_ARRAY` and call `free(array[i])`
**What you put in place of `...` in your code is very important**.

**In general**, when allocating memory, be sure to respect these general ideas:

- If a functions allocates memory it frees it itself except when it is needed outside afterwards.
- If a function allocates memory needed outside afterwards, it does just this.

This allows for better code architecture and easier freeing of the memory.

For example:

First point:

```
void foo()
{
  char *a;

  a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * 5);
  a[0] = 'a';
  a[1] = 'b';
  a[2] = 'c';
  a[3] = 'd';
  a[4] = 0; //or '\0' if you prefer
  do_something_cool(a);
  free(a);
}
```

The function `foo` allocates memory, processes it, and frees it.

Second point:

```
char *halfstrdup(char *str)
{
  int len;
  int i;
  char *newstr;

  len = strlen(str);
  newstr = malloc(sizeof(*newstr) * len / 2)
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    if ((i % 2) == 0)
      newstr[i / 2] = str[i];
  }
  return (newstr);
}

void foo2()
{
  char *half;

  half = halfstrdup("Hello, world !");
  do_something_cooler(half);
  free(half);
}
```

The function `halfstrdup` just allocates and sets the memory you need and returns it, the function `foo2` allocates memory through the use of `halfstrdup`, then uses it and frees it.

**Do not forget to free before losing track of your pointers**, for example after returning from foo or foo2, you won't be able to free the allocated memory.

Comment: thanks for the long answer, but this does not handle my problem.

Comment: How does it not handle your problem? Have you looked at least the first part of my answer?

Comment: My problem is a call-by-reference allocation and i am not able to free it again. your first example: everything in same function. second example: return value. No call by reference.

Comment: There is no such thing as "references" in C. What you pass to your function is the address of your variable `array`, you store there the address of `malloc`'d memory, where you store other malloc'd memory addresses. You have to first free the pointers contained in the first allocated piece of memory, which is your array "cells".